# How to store pid of current page with the SaveToDatabaseFinisher and TYPO3 EXT:Form

Tags: forms, typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-form

I want to store the form data in the database using the SaveToDatabaseFinisher. The data should be assigned to the page, where the form Plugin is placed on and I don't know how to find the `pid` of the current page. In every example I found, the pid was always hard coded in the yaml file.

I tried `{pid}` and `{__pid}` without any success. So how to get the current page's id (pid) to store it in the database (in TYPO3 8.7)? Or is it only possible in a later T3 release?

```
  ...
  databaseColumnMappings:
    pid:
      value: '{__pid}'
    tstamp:
      value: '{__currentTimestamp}'
  elements:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since runtime references are currently not extensible besides form values you need to add a custom finisher which determines the current page ID and [stores it as finisher variable](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/8.7/en-us/Concepts/FrontendRendering/Index.html#share-data-between-finishers). Then you can access this variable in the `SaveToDatabase` finisher configuration.